# Revert shadow copy using interface ivsssoftwaresnapshotprovider for windows clients

Tags: visual-c++, com

Can someone help me on how to use this API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vsprov/nf-vsprov-ivsssoftwaresnapshotprovider-reverttosnapshot.

This API is used to restore the previous shadow copy. My motive is to resotre the shadow copy for windows clients like win10 or win7. I am able to do for servers using IVssBackupComponents::RevertToSnapshot(). But this API is used only for servers. Please anyone suggest if used the API ivsssoftwaresnapshotprovider.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically I want to restore shadow copy image in client OS. So please suggest how to do that.